# Bash executing multiple commands in background in same line

Tags: bash, shell

When i try to execute

```
-bash-3.2$ cd /scratch/;nohup sh xyz.sh>>del.txt &;exit
```

I am getting following error..

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

I am trying to run a detached process using nohup .. & . ';' works fine for all other commands except `nohup sh xyz.sh>>del.txt &;`

can anyone tell the problem here . Thanks

Comment: try putting spaces before and after ";"

Comment: Remove the `;` after `&` since `&` is a command separator by itself.

Comment: I used space before and after ';' .I am using '&' not as a separator but to indicate it as a detached process .

Comment: @KannanRG We know that `&` is used to run a process in the background.  It acts as a command separator, too!  So the `;` after that causes the error.  `bash` doesn't accept _blank_ commands.

Comment: Shell - Multiple commands in one line , answer works for all other commands except for "nohup sh xyz.sh>>del.txt & ; exit"

Comment: @KannanRG How many times?  Remove the `;` after `&`.  You were already told to do so.

Comment: @devnull got you now .sorry didn't understood you were suggesting the answer . i thought you were mentioning the problem .its working fine now .. thanks.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is *not* the same as this question. Neither the dupe nor its answers covered the case where you wanted to run one of the commands in the background with `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer:**
as @CharlesDuffy correctly remarked; my old answer created a subshell, which is entirely unnecessary. In fact the `&` sign also terminates the line; so no more need to add an extra `;`. Bash is complaining because a single line containing only a `;` is not a valid command. Bash reads your command as:

```
cd /scratch/
nohup sh xyz.sh>>del.txt &
;
exit
```

Therefore you should just remove the `;` after your nohup line, and (again; thanks @CharlesDuffy); only call the nohup command if you succeeded to enter the `/scratch/` directory; using `&&` means the next command is executed only if the first one succeeds.

```
cd /scratch/ && nohup sh xyz.sh>>del.txt & exit
```

<strike>**Old answer:**</strike>

You can try putting your command between quotes if you are in a bash shell

```
cd /scratch/ ; `nohup sh xyz.sh>>del.txt &` ; exit
```

you can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161252/bash-start-multiple-chained-commands-in-background)

Comment: thanks , this worked for me . Removing ';' after '&' as @devnull suggested also worked for me .

Comment: This has significant performance overhead -- it creates an otherwise-entirely-unnecessary `fork()`ed subshell, and for no benefit over the version without the command substitution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : thanks for the remark. I wrote this answer 4 years ago and am quite ashamed of it now. I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update it. (BTW, I'd also suggest `cd /scratch && nohup ...` to avoid the risk of running the command in the wrong directory if the `cd` fails).

Answer (score 9):

As per the `bash` manpage:

> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated by one of `;`, `&`, or `<newline>`.
>
> If  a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.  Commands separated by a `;` are executed sequentially; the shell waits for each command to terminate in turn.  The return status is the exit status of the last command executed.

You can see there that `&` isn't just something that runs a command in the background, it's actually a *separator* as well. Hence, you don't *need* the semicolon following it. In fact, it's actually *invalid* to try that, just the same as if you put two semicolons in sequence, the actual problem being that `bash` does not permit empty commands:

```
pax> echo 1 ; echo 2
1
2

pax> echo 1 ; ; echo 2
bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'
```

---

You can see how this works from the following transcript, where the second and third dates are *not* separated because the `sleep 10` runs in the background:

```
pax> date ; sleep 5 ; date ; sleep 10 & date ; wait
Thursday 5 April  09:04:07 AWST 2018
Thursday 5 April  09:04:12 AWST 2018
[1] 28999
Thursday 5 April  09:04:12 AWST 2018
[1]+  Done                    sleep 10
```

Comment: This is entirely correct, but it'd be easier to upvote if it actually showed an example of doing something like `foo & bar &` to run multiple commands in the background, as the title calls for.