# Wait for a proccess to finish

Tags: bash

Could you please help me with any hint about the below issue?

i have to send a command to a host (the command needs lot of time to execute and creates a file):

```
ssh uname1@host1 ssh uname2@host2 'command1'
```

after this command gets executed i need to zip the file created

```
ssh uname1@host1 ssh uname2@host2 'gzip file1'
```

Than do the same thing for another host

```
ssh uname3@host3 ssh uname4@host4 'command1'
ssh uname1@host1 ssh uname2@host2 'gzip file2'
```

Is it possible to run both this commands in parallel in order to save time for script execution?
thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with 'both commands'? 'command1' and `gzip`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash: start multiple chained commands in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161252/bash-start-multiple-chained-commands-in-background)

Comment: i need to run the commands in the background and notify me when they're finished.
since the command is a depened one (varies) i cannot put these commands in the remote host!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like

```
ssh uname2@host2 'command1 && gzip file1' &
ssh uname2@host3 'command1 && gzip file1' &
ssh uname2@host4 'command1 && gzip file1' &
```

You can put all the commands in a file on the host you start from

`&&` in this context works like `;` but the second command is only executed if the first works

Comment: You're missing the initial `ssh`, but this is the right idea.

Comment: In fact the command is a variable (depended input) so i can't put them in file in the remote host.

Comment: Here's how to pass a variable from the "start" host ``X="fish" ssh -t host1 ssh -t host2 "echo $X;uname; hostname"``  The ``"`` quotes get interpolated for the shell that starts the command, so $X is set from there

Answer (score 2):

Simply do:

```
ssh uname1@host1 ssh uname2@host2 'command1; gzip file1'
```

and if the gzip should be run only is the first command is a success, then :

```
ssh uname1@host1 ssh uname2@host2 'command1 && gzip file1'
```

The second command will be launched after the first one.

Comment: if i use
ssh uname1@host1 ssh uname2@host2 'command1; gzip file1' &
the command runs in the background, how to know it's finished so i can get the file via ftp/sftp?