# LINUX sh script queue

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on one project and I need to convert videos to different formats with avconv. Problem is I do not want them to run simultaneously in background. So I had idea to have *.txt file and SH script will check first line (it will be script) and "run" that forst line and delete it meanwhile, after finishing it will again run first line and delete it.

How could i possibly do that? Sorry if it is so easy, cuz i have never worked with file reading before in Linux SH scripts.

Comment: I believe an example would help your question, since the English is not very clear. Also, if you are not very familiar with shell, then perhaps it is not a good language for your problem. Do you know other programming languages?

Comment: See: [**bash: start multiple chained commands in background**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161252/bash-start-multiple-chained-commands-in-background)

Comment: If the number is not too lengthy, you can always run them in a subshell sequentially and background the subshell. e.g. `$ ( avconv file1.avi;  avconv file2.avi;  avconv file3.avi ) &`.  You can also create compound statements:  `$ ( avconv file1.avi &&  avconv file2.avi &&  avconv file3.avi ) &`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run lots of `avconv` jobs one after the other, put them in a shell script and run them like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
avconv <abc> <def>
avconv <ghi> <jkl>
avconv ...
```

If you mean that you want to continuously append jobs to the file after it has started running, you need a *"job queue"* which you can easily make with `GNU Parallel`.

Basically, you create your initial file with a bunch of `avconv` commands in it, or just make an empty file and use that. Then start `GNU Parallel` processing the jobs

```
touch jobqueue                          # make empty list of jobs
tail -n+0 -f jobqueue | parallel -j1    # start GNU Parallel processing them, -j1 means one at a time
```

Then when you have a new job, `echo` it to the end of the queue like this

```
echo avconv param1 param2 >> jobqueue
```

See the relevant section in the manpage by typing

```
man parallel
/jobqueue <Enter>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer just key question - you can use `tail` command (and maybe also `head` command will be handy). Another question is whole task you want to achieve, I think it is much more complicated than just cutting first line, but good luck with that.

To "edit" - filter out first line :

```
tail -n +2 input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

Then you could move output_file over input_file (`mv output_file.txt input_file.txt`)

Similarly, you can get just first line from text file by:

```
head -n 1 input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do something with each line of a file, then you can do it easily like this:

```
while read line; do
  echo $line
done < file.txt
```

This will iterate through `file.txt` and print each line. You can for example use each line as arguments to a program like this:

```
while read line; do
  theprogram $line
done < file.txt
```

This will run `theprogram` for each line using the line as `theprogram`'s arguments.

Please note that by using this approach, the `file.txt` is not modified (the lines are not extracted from the file). Which may or may not be what you want.